# Data truncated in MySQL database I need more idea what causes this?

Tags: mysql, database, truncation

I always got this warning message everytime I insert data row for username and password. The function I used is MD5 for password and Current User for username.

What I did is leaving the function blank for username and password, and now it inserted successfully without warning, but of course I can't leave password unencypted.

I tried to search the internet for this kind of problem but they are complicated to understand. What I need to know is what causes this problem everytime I set the function for the row the warning occur?

This is the warning says.

> 1 row inserted.
>
> Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'username' at row 1
>
> Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'password' at row 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means that the length of the value you are inserting is **greater than** the length defined on the column.

Alter the columns `username` and `password` to length 32 because MD5 returns a string of 32 hex digits.

Comment: I don't think so I set the length for the value for column 20 and I inserted just 5 or 10 characters in row.

Comment: can you execute this: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'`  and post the result here?

Comment: Weird but you are right I set it to 35 and now inserted without warning. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a password, when encrypted with, comes with a bigger character sequence. So for safe inserting make your password length for minimum 50 characters. We have implemented this in production application, and this has not caused us any problem for atleast 2 years. We have seen that md5 encrypted password comes to 28 charaters and higher.

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Please check the password field in your model, whether max_lengh is greater than 128

password = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='password', help_text="password")